# How can I convert <class 'str'> into <class '__main__'> in Python

Tags: python, class, pointers

```
class P:
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x
    def __repr__(self):
        return f"p{self.x}"
    def a(self):
        print(self.x)        
a = P(10)
print(a, type(a))    # p10 <class '__main__.P'>
b = str(a)
print(b, type(b))    # p10 <class 'str'>

c = ????
```

For variable 'c' I would like to convert 'b' back into pointer p10. So I inspect to return for code

```
print(a.x, c.x)
```

10 10

I understand that the simple solution is c = a, but I need to convert class 'str' into pointer.

Solution with dictionary, dynamically adding objects

```
lst = [1, 3, 7, 4]
d = {}
for i in lst:
    x = P(i)
    d[str(x)] = x
d['p3'].a()
d['p7'].a()
```

I thought that there is a solution without additional dictionary.

Comment: `b` is a string object, which is not obtained by casting the type of `a`, and has nothing to do with `a` since it was constructed...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python is a strongly typed language (this is not conflict with dynamic types). After a variable is created, its type is determined. `str(a)` is not similar to the syntax of `(str *) a` in C language. It will not cast the type of object a like C, but constructs a brand-new `str` object through the parameter `a` you pass in. The resulting object is independent of `a` itself.

If you want your `P` object can be restored from the converted `str` object, the only thing you can do is customize `__str__` (or `__repr__` in your example) megic method of `P` to serialize it and use `__init__` method of `P` to deserialize.

Comment: Initially, I wanted to create objects dynamically. For example:

lst = [1, 3, 7, 4]
d = {}
for i in lst:
    x = P(i)
    d[str(x)] = x
d['p3'].a()
d['p7'].a()

I thought that there is a solution without additional dictionary. Unfortunately python is not such a flexible language. Thank you for reply.